# outline img hover not working in ie

Tags: jquery, css

```
div img:hover {
outline:2px solid #4d3326;
}
```

The above code is not working in ie , its working fine in firefox and chrome , may i know what is the problem or any alternative

Thanks

Comment: don't you want `border: 2px solid #4d3326`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE6/7 don't support `outline`, you can see which browser's support it on quirksmode here: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t26

Further, [IE6 doesn't support `:hover` on an `<img>` either](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t16), so it's double-broken there :)

Comment: and IE6 doesn't support hover on the img element.

Comment: @ScottE - yup, was already adding this, took me a bit to find the link id :)

Comment: Then how can i add image border on mouseover , do i need to wrap around a div and add div border on mouseover??

Answer (score 0):

From [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_outline.asp):

> Internet Explorer 8 (and higher) supports the outline property if a !DOCTYPE is specified.

So either you're using IE6 or IE7, or you don't have a doctype specified.!DOCTYPE is specified.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other posts you can't use `:hover` for an image in IE, it works only on `<a>` tags, nor does it support `outline` in versions below 8.

An alternative would be to wrap your image in an **anchor**.

```
<a href="#" class="imagehover">
     <img src="bg_panel_corners.png" alt="" />
</a>
```

And then you can use a **border** on the anchor

```
.imagehover:hover{border:2px solid #4d3326}
```

I do realise this may not be ideal. If so you can use javascript to enable `:hover` on none `<a>` elements, take a look at [this article](http://www.visibilityinherit.com/code/ie6-hover-javascript.php)